# Did the EU Referendum Act 2015 mandate “the leaflet”?

Tags: united-kingdom, brexit

Did the EU Referendum Act 2015 mandate the delivery of a leaflet to every household advocating the Government’s position?

Comment: Have you tried reading the act itself? The language on what it requited a minister to do is fairly clear. http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2015/36/pdfs/ukpga_20150036_en.pdf

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it primarily seems an excuse for a rant in the form of an answer.

Comment: I posed an honest question. It was then suggested I research the answer myself. So I did, and added the answer for others to benefit from. I’m interested: what makes my answer a rant?

Comment: The last two paragraphs. While the rest is pretty much a description of the act, none of that details why the format decisions were made. It is pure speculation and makes no acknowledgement of the internal division within the Tory party or what effect that may have had. It is likely that the pro-leave portions of the party would not have wanted the kind of information you suggest to be published by the government as it would have limited the scope of their own campaign literature/ads.

Comment: There is no speculation in my answer. If it were speculative I might have pontificated on the reasons for the observed behaviour. My answer is purely descriptive. The first part describes the contents of the Act (not speculative). The penultimate paragraph describes a possible alternative that would have met the requirements of the Act (pertinent to the question - an alternative _was_ possible). The final paragraph describes what the Government actually did. All descriptive. No speculation,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The medium was described as “a report” and the style of delivery was left unstated in the Act.

The requirements for publication of information are set out in Sections 6 and 7 of the [The Act](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2015/36/pdfs/ukpga_20150036_en.pdf).

The following information needed to be published:

1. The outcome of the negotiations with the EU (Subsection 6.1)
2. The opinion of the Government on the outcome of the negotiations (Subsection 6.2)
3. Information about membership of the European Union (rights, obligations etc.) (Subsection 7.1)

The medium to be used was described as “a report” and the style of publication was left unstated. No mention of a leaflet or the posting to every household is made.

So, for example, a leaflet or website setting out both sides of the debate would have met the requirement.

In the event, the Government decided to meet the requirements of the Act by spending £9.3 million to deliver a leaflet to every household setting out the case for Remain (their position, thereby meeting the terms of the Act) without setting out the other side of the argument.